# How to append to a file after File.CreateText?

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# app that needs to create a CSV file.

The problem is after issuing a File.CreateText({file path}), I cannot immediately write to it. If the file already exists, I can write no problem. Here is the code:

```
if (!File.Exists(file_name))
        {

            File.CreateText(file_name);
            File.WriteAllText(file_name, String.Format("Old Name,Short Name{0}", this.old_name_txt.Text, this.new_name_txt.Text, Environment.NewLine));
        }
        else
        {
            File.AppendAllText(file_name, String.Format("{0},{1}{2}", this.old_name_txt.Text, this.new_name_txt.Text, Environment.NewLine));
        }
```

After creating the file, I have also tried "File.AppendAllText..."

The error it is producing says that it cannot write because the file is being used by another process.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `File.CreateText`?

Comment: YEs, sorry. I forgot to mention I tried that method and got the same error. Then I shortened it to this.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for reminding me. I got busy and forgot to come back and mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.CreateText` will create a text file and open the file. It then returns a `StreamWriter` which you could use to access that created file. Because you opened the file like this already, you will get an error when trying to open that file again.

When reading the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `File.CreateText` make sure to look at the **return value** as well, to understand what the function does.

Please read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `File.AppendAllText` as well and then change your code accordingly.

Here's the most important part in the docs:

> *AppendAllText(String, String)*
>   **Description**
>   Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

You should be able to solve your problem by yourself now.